# Que es lo mas adecuado en cuanto al uso de los mensajes en un proyecto de windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Muy buena comunidad, me gustaría saber lo que piensan y que me den sus puntos de vista sobre la programacion en tres capas
tengo un proyecto pequeño el cual lo estoy intentando realizar en tres capas, ahora les mostrare mis tres capas.

Como verán en ambos métodos tengo el try catch
y en ambos métodos tengo los mensajes y pues cuando se inserta un registro me salen ambos mensajes.
mi pregunta es, en que capa debo tener los mensajes, he leído en internet que no es buena práctica tener los mensajes en la capa de datos, y otros que dicen que es conforme a los requerimientos de mi proyecto.
Ahora mi duda es cual es la mejor práctica o la mas acercada a lo correcto
por favor si me pueden ayudar con algunos ejemplos y explicarme cual es mejor y su porque

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

```
public void InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertarEstado", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", estado.Nombre);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MostrarMensaje("Estado insertado correctamente.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MostrarMensaje("Error al insertar el estado: " + ex.Message, false);
            }
        }
```

Ahora mi capa presentación

```
private void InsertarEstado()
        {
            RN_Estados rN_Estados = new RN_Estados();
            EN_Estados eN_Estados = new EN_Estados();
            try
            {
                eN_Estados.Nombre = txtEstado.Text;
                rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados);
                // Mostrar un mensaje de éxito.
                MessageBox.Show("Estado agregado correctamente.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               // Manejar el error.
            MessageBox.Show("Error al insertar el estado: " + ex.Message, "CAPA PRESENTACIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Recuerda que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Delimita tu pregunta a un problema _específico_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con base a la arquitectura de tu software, **lo correcto es tener los mensajes en la capa de Presentación** debido a que se encarga de tener comunicación con la **capa de Acceso a Datos**, por lo tanto, controla las condiciones y funcionalidades del nivel de sistema y de la aplicación.

**--Mensaje de error**

Por ejemplo, en ambos códigos tienes definida la **estructura Try-Catch** entonces, cuando se produce una excepción el sistema busca la estructura **catch** más cercana para controlar el error. Por lo tanto, toma la estructura que está definida en tu **capa de Acceso a Datos** y posteriormente toma la estructura que está definida en tu **capa de Presentación**. Es por eso que se muestran ambos mensajes.

Con base al ejemplo anterior, se puede quitar la estructura catch que esta definida en tu capa de Acceso a Datos por qué aún así, en caso de producirse una excepción, la estructura definida en la capa de Presentación lo podrá capturar y mostrará el mensaje
de error.

**--Mensaje de éxito**

Para la muestra del mensaje de éxito lo correcto es definirlo en la **capa de Presentación** igualmente, ya que al ejecutarse correctamente, tu método **InsertarEstado definido en la capa de Acceso a Datos** volverá a tu capa de Presentación sin ninguna excepción y procederá a mostrar el mensaje de éxito.

Un posible ejemplo de mala práctica **(al menos de que los requerimiento del proyecto no lo requieran)** es el siguiente:

Ejecutar tu método **InsertarEstado de la capa de Acceso a Datos** repetidamente, esto ocasionaría que por cada sentencia ejecutada correctamente, se mostraría el mensaje de éxito por cada registro. Esto podría ser un problema en la capa de Presentación

Comment: De antemano gracias por aclcarar mi panorama, ahora que pasaría si quito el try y catch del codigo de mi método de la capa de datos?

Comment: La verdad que la opción número 2 es muy buena, porque aveces voy a necesitar saber si una cabecera de código se ingresó, para poder recien guardar su detalle.
public bool InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
{
    try
    {
       //El código
       return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private void InsertarEstado()
{
    //el código
    if(rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados)){
       //lanzamos mensaje de "success"
    }
    else{
      //lamanzamos mensaje de error
    }
}
ahora, por favor como obtengo el error en la CPrese

Answer (score 1):

Separemos 2 aspectos

- El mensaje (el texto ha mostrar)
- `MessageBox.Show`

El uso de `MessageBox.Show` es claramente un tema de presentación (una ventana que muestra un mensaje. Por otro lado "El mensaje", puede ser algo más difuso y depender de la situación.

**Ejemplo 1:** Cada vez que insertas un estado deseas lanzar un `MessageBox.Show`, esto es así siempre para todos los casos. Aquí es perfectamente válido retornar un string como mensaje.

```
public string InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertarEstado", connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 20;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", estado.Nombre);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "Estado insertado correctamente.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error al insertar el estado: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

```
private void InsertarEstado()
{
    RN_Estados rN_Estados = new RN_Estados();
    EN_Estados eN_Estados = new EN_Estados();

    eN_Estados.Nombre = txtEstado.Text;
    string resultado = rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados);
    MessageBox.Show(resultado);
}
```

Puedes ver como el código queda bastante limpio, ¿El problema? es que carece de versatilidad.

---

**Ejemplo 2:** Imagina que el mensaje que queremos mostrar cambia según el si ha habido error o no. Por ejemplo, el mensaje muestra un icono rojo cuando hay un error ❌ y un icono verde cuando la operación se concretó correctamente ✅

Ya no sirve retornar el mensaje, por lo que podemos retonar un booleano (esta es mi opción favorita)

```
public bool InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
{
    try
    {
       //El código
       return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
private void InsertarEstado()
{
    //el código
    if(rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados)){
       //lanzamos mensaje de "success"
    }
    else{
      //lamanzamos mensaje de error
    }
}
```

---

**Ejemplo 3:** Ahora pensemos en un escenario completamente distinto, donde tu código no sabes quien y como lo va usar. Como por ejemplo estas desarrollando una libreria para terceros, o estas en un equipo de trabajo donde cada un es responsable de su código. Aquí lo normal es manejar la Exception y volver a arrojar una nueva Exception (o la misma), con lo que tienes que colocar en ambas partes un try/catch

```
public void InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
{
    try
    {
       //El código
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //aqui puedo guardar la Exception en un log
        
        //throw; //para lanzar la misma Exception

        throw new Exception(ex.Message); //para lanzar una nueva

        //throw new MyCustomException(ex.Message); //para lanzar una personalizada

    }
}
```

```
private void InsertarEstado()
{
    //el código

    //debemos colocar nuevamente un try/catch
    try{
      rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados)
    }
    else{
      //lamanzamos mensaje de error
    }
}
```

---

**Ejemplo 4** En un comentario preguntas que pasa si sacamos el try/catch de la  primera función (la que conecta con la BD) y la dejamos solo para la segunda función. Como supongo sabrás esto es perfectamente posible, ya que la segunda función manejaría la excepción, haciendo que el programa no se colgara

```
public void InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)
{
   //El código sin try/catch
}
```

```
private void InsertarEstado()
{
    //el código
    try{
      rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados)
    }
    else{
      //lamanzamos mensaje de error
    }
}
```

Pero, **no es una buena opción**. Primero hay un asunto de lógica en la responsabilidad de cada función. Es la función que conecta con la base de datos la que puede arrojar una Exception, por tanto es su responsabilidad manejarla.

Luego puede pasar que a esta función la invocas desde varias partes, tendrás que colocar un try/cath en cada una de las otras funciones y basta que olvides colocarlo en una función para que tu aplicación tenga un riesgo no forzado (y nosotros SIEMPRE queremos tener menos riesgos). Y aunque tuvieras cuidado, produce un código más limpio el tener un solo try/catch (donde debe estar) y no muchos repartidos en todos lados

---

Si analizas todos los casos, te darás cuenta porque mi opción favorita es el `Ejemplo 2`

- Es versátil
- Produce con código limpia sin excesos de try/catch
- El responsable de manejar la excepción es quien debe ser

Debo aclarar que este caso es fácil, porque tu función `InsertarEstado(EN_Estados estado)` es `void`. El asunto de cual opción es mejor puede cambiar drásticamente para los casos en que la función retorna un objeto, ya que no puedes simplemente cambiar el retorno a `bool` (porque estas usando dicho retorno para otra cosa)

Comment: Que paciencia para enseñar o saacr6de duda a los demás, gracias. Ahora pregunto eso de usar messagebox. Show en la capa de datos, y usar el using para windows.forms entonces no es del todo una mala práctica?

Comment: MessageBox.show es puramente capa de presentación.

Comment: @RobertoCarlosMelgar En programación la mayoría de las veces la respuesta es "Depende".  Pero en este caso, es seguro que `messagebox. Show` va siempre en la presentación . Lo que yo te señalo en las primeras líneas de mi respuesta, es que el "Mensaje" (solo el texto), puede ir en otra capa (si es que te facilita la vida), y luego en la capa de presentación tu decides si ese mensaje lo muestras al usuario en un  `messagebox. Show`, o en un `label` o en un form personalizado o en lo que decidas.